# Trouble installing imagick on Debian Stretch and php 7.2

Tags: linux, debian, php, imagemagick

I have a Debian Stretch machine with php 7.2 on which Joomla is running happily.

I need now to add the PHP imagick module to handle images.

It doesn't matter how I try to install imagick, it never appears in php ! I installed it with apt, manually modified php.ini and restarted Apache. All dependencies are there as far as i can see.

[Last try was to follow this method that worked also](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/292/howto-install-imagemagick-php-extension-pecl-imagick-debian).

After install, the imagick tests passed successfully. But when i try to see if php "sees" imagick with :

> php -m | grep imagick

i get no answer...

Any idea how i can make this work ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [su]! I'm not a PHP guru, but I think a few things are missing from your question: Why doesn't `apt-get` work for you? And, why can't you use [the `pecl` command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php#111389) to install the it?

Comment: Hi. apt DID work without any warning, but php doesn't see imagick. That's why i tried another method, but didn't help... I'm not familiar with apt-get or pecl..
I'm behin a proxy which does'nt help..

Comment: apt is the new form of apt-get. Did you install PHP with apt, or via another method?

Comment: OK thanks. Yes i installed php 7.2 with apt using the sury repos.

Comment: Hi, TK5EP. Since this question involves installing development tools, it would also be on-topic on Stack Overflow. I recommend deleting this question, and then reposting to [SO]. Be sure to include all of the above information, plus anything else you think might be relevant.